# Is there any way to make a manual join using Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, backend, django-queryset

lets say I have the following models:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(ModelA):
    pass

class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

class ModelD(models.Model):
    model_c = models.ForeingKey(ModelC)
```

And I need to filter all the instances of ModelD that have a relation in ModelB. Is there any way to remove the unnecesary joins in the query that the queryset will produce ?

`ModelD.objects.filter(model_c__model_a__model_b__id__isnull=False)`

If there's any way to make a filter like this:

`ModelD.objects.filter(model_c__model_b__id__isnull=False)`

I know how to make the query on SQL, but for terms of readabilty and code maintenance I would like to know if there's any way to make the manual join or to remove that intermediate join.

Thanks in advance for the replies !

Edit:
I want to use the field that the inheritance of ModelA in ModelB generates, the one that's called `app_modelb.modela_ptr_id` in the database

Comment: Have you looked at select_related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Yes, I tried used select_related, but it still fetched the ModelA table for the query,  which is the thing Im trying to avoid for optimization purposes

Answer (score 0):

For this to be true, you should have a field `model_b` that is foreign-key to `ModelB` in the model `ModelC`. That is how the query works in Django (or any other framework that plays with databases).

Comment: Yes, but since Django generates the `OneToOneField` automatically I thought there's a way to filter through the `app_modelb.modela_ptr_id` field